# 2d arrays memory map in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array

i've been doing various problems on 2D array in C.Each problem is like hitting another coconut on my head,as every problem uses different approach.For instance some use "take 2D array(like  a[2][4]),now this creates two arrays,one of the arrays is of size 2, containing address of each row of 2D array(like this is having two rows,each of four values)".While other approaches treat is as contiguous 1D array representation.now which approach to use. A proper memory map would be a great help.below is sample problem to workout.

```
int main()
{ 
   unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 
                           {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
   printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
}

output:2036,2036,2036
```

now ,if it was first approach ,how come address of x+3 and *(x+3) be the same?

Comment: The memory layout is a block of 12 contiguous ints. Your might be able to answer your own question better if you use array index notation instead. Remember that `*(a+b)` means `a[b]`.  So you are printing `&x[3]`, `&x[3][0]`, and `&x[2][3]`.    The first of those is the address of an array, the other two are the address of an int.

Comment: `%p` for address,.....

Answer (score 4):

Built-in arrays in C language *always* use the "second" approach (per your numbering), no exceptions. Every time you declare 1D, 2D, 3D or whatever-D array, as in your sample code, that array is laid out in memory as a contiguous memory block - as an 1D array of "combined" size (i.e. all sizes multipled).

The "first" approach can only be used in "manually" assembled arrays (so called "jagged" or "ragged" arrays). The language will not use this approach for representing explcitly declared multi-dimensional arrays.

However, it is undefined behavior to use `%u` format specifier to print pointer values. Stop doing this. Function `printf` provides `%p` format for printing pointers.

In `x + 3` expression, object `x` of type `unsigned [4][3]` implicitly decays to a value of type `unsigned (*)[3]` - a pointer that points to `x[0]` subarray. Per rules of pointer arithmetic, `x + 3` is a value of `unsigned (*)[3]` type that points to `x[3]` subarray.

The same thing initially happens in `*(x + 3)` expression, except that the `x + 3` (which, again, points to `x[3]` subarray) gets dereferenced by `*` operator and becomes `x[3]` subarray itself. In context of `print` argument, this subarray immediately decays to a value of `unsigned *` type that points to `x[3][0]`.

So, even though the results of `x + 3` and `*(x + 3)` have different types, they still point to exactly the same location in memory. This is why the pointer values look the same numerically.

The same thng would happen in the following simple example

```
int main()
{
  int a[10];
  printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &a, (void *) &a[0]);
}
```

The output will show the same numerical value of both pointers. Your example is a bit more convoluted, but the same in essence.

Comment: can you please explain me the above problem with this.if possible memory map. @ant